# How to perform nested serialization in Django?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

I am new to Django.I am using Django REST Framework and I need to get json from serializers in the following format:

```
 {
    "result"      : 200,
    "categories"    : [{
        "id"  : "V001",
        "name": "Vehicles",
        "description": "All types of motor and non-motor vehicles",
        "icon": "http://images.maa.ae/static/icons/vehicles.png",
        "subcategories": [{
            "id"  : "V00101",
            "name": "Cars",
            "description": "Motor Cars",
            "subcategories": [{
                "id"  : "V0010101",
                "name": "Passenger Cars",
                "description": "All types of passenger cars"
            }]
        },
        {
            "id"  : "V00102",
            "name": "Bikes",
            "description": "Bikes",
            "subcategories": [{
                "id"  : "V0010201",
                "name": "Motor Bikes",
                "description": "All kinds of motor bikes"
            },
            {
                "id"  : "V0010202",
                "name": "Sports Bikes",
                "description": "All kinds of sports bikes"
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

My Model class is:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    _id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=150,null=True, blank=True)
    icon = models.ImageField(upload_to='icons',null=True, blank=True)
    parent_id = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)
```

and my serializers class is:

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('_id', 'name', 'description', 'icon')
```

From above implementation I can get Array of Category objects in JSON format.

But I don't know how can I include 'subcategories' in my serializer class.Please help me to get an output similar to json shown in above format.

Comment: What exactly is your question? How to retrieve something from a database? How to create JSON? Please [edit] your question to be much more specific, with only one question. Additionally, please add the code you are working with, the full text of any errors or tracebacks you are receiving, and a thorough description of what exactly the problem is. As it stands, this question is quite unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Use Django Rest Framework.

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/

Keep your code DRY

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class CategoriesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Categories
```

Views

```
 from rest_framework import viewsets

 from .serializers import CategoriesSerializer

 class CategoryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
     queryset = Categories.objects.all()
     serializer_class = CategoriesSerializer
```

Example

models.py:

```
class Sprints(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(default='', blank=True, max_length=90)
    description = models.TextField(default='')


class Tasks(models.Model):
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    name = models.CharField(default='', blank=True, max_length=90)
    end = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    sprint = models.ForeignKey(Sprints, related_name='tasks')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date_posted']
        unique_together = ['name', 'sprint']
```

serializers.py:

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tasks
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'date_posted', 'end')

class SprintSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tasks = TaskSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Sprints
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'description', 'tasks')
```

views.py

```
class SprintsViews(viewset.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Sprints.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SprintSerializer
```

You can also add a slug field to the models to make them easier to deal with, but this is how for now :)

Comment: Thanks for helping, I was using django-rest framework. My real probelm is about nested serialization. I need to include subcategories in my response  Which is of type 'Category' as shown in my question.

Comment: Have you tried the hyperlinked relations? http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/5-relationships-and-hyperlinked-apis/ If you need more help I can post a specific example I'm using in a scrum app

Comment: Thanks for the reply,I have tried hyperlinked relations, Since I am new to django I feel quite harder to understand that.Can you please provide your example?

Comment: This is just for representation in the way you wanted, we can add slugs and do all kinds of stuff! For now I recommend the book "Lightweight-Django"

Answer (score 0):

You should consider having a look at [THIS](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization). The usage of `depth` meta attribute enables you to retrieve related objects to the depth you set.

By doing so, it automatically retrieves nested data.

It is very convenient to avoid using serializers in both sides and thus having ImportError caused by cycles too.

Answer (score 0):

Use `related_name` and `on_delete` on your `parent_id` field in `models.py` file

```
class Category(models.Model):
    _id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=150,null=True, blank=True)
    icon = models.ImageField(upload_to='icons',null=True, blank=True)
    parent_id = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now add the packege `pip install djangorestframework-recursive` on your project

`serializers.py`:

```
##################################
from rest_framework_recursive.fields import RecursiveField
##################################

class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    children = RecursiveField(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('_id', 'name', 'description', 'icon', 'parent_id', 'children')
```

`views.py` (Serializers view file):

```
class CategoryListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
    queryset = Category.objects.filter(parent_id__isnull=True)
```

`urls.py`:

```
############################
############################

urlpatterns = [
    path('category/', views.CategoryListAPIView.as_view(), name="categoryAPI"),
    ######################################
]
```